# How to create multiple edges from one vertex in single traversal

Tags: java, tinkerpop3, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I've got function which has this signature:

`public void doTheJob(String from, Collection<Pair<String, String>> relations)`

where:

`from` is a unique value the graph should be asked about

`relations` is a collection of pair, where first element from pair is edge `label` and the second is similar to `from` but it designates the second side of the relation. Eg ( assuming that andy, dog are unique ):

`"andy" ["has,dog", "has,cat", "is,person"]`

I would like to add these edges between these vertices ( they are already existing in graph, i would like to query them and create edges between them ). The requirement I've got is to prepare this in one traversal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.addV().property('name','cat').
......1>   addV().property('name','dog').
......2>   addV().property('name','person').iterate()
gremlin> markoRelations = [['has','dog'],['has','cat'],['is','person']];[]
gremlin> joshRelations = [['has','dog'],['is','person']];[]
gremlin> t = g.V().has('name','marko').as('from');[]
gremlin> markoRelations.each { t = t.V().has('name',it[1]).
......1>                             addE(it[0]).from('from') };[]
gremlin> t.iterate()
gremlin> t = g.V().has('name','josh').as('from');[]
gremlin> joshRelations.each { t = t.V().has('name',it[1]).
......1>                            addE(it[0]).from('from') };[]
gremlin> t.iterate()
gremlin> g.E().hasLabel('is','has')
==>e[19][1-has->15]
==>e[20][1-has->13]
==>e[21][1-is->17]
==>e[22][4-has->15]
==>e[23][4-is->17]
```

Don't be distracted by the Groovy syntax too much and just focus on on the Gremlin and structure. `markoRelations` and `joshRelations` are just lists of list where the inner list is basically you `Pair`. The `;[]` you see at the end of lines is not relevant to the answer - it just helps control the output that the Gremlin Console will show.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you! One thing which is not exactly as the question specifies is that you are creating vertices here: ```addV().property('name',it[1])).addE(it[0]).from('from')```. Please make this traversal to find the already existing vertex. I will then approve your answer.

Comment: well - it's already finding the existing vertex and only creating it if isn't there with use of `coalesce()` but ok, i misread your question and i removed that - it's even easier to follow now